# ExpressJS branching routes based on request parameters

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have 4 middleware functions: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

If the body contains a value `X`, I want to execute `a` then `b`, else I want to execute `c` then `d`.

My code looks like this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.X) {
    next();
  } else {
    next('route');
    return;
  }
}, a, b);

app.post('/', c, d);
```

Is there a more elegant way for this? Is there a way (or package) that makes these kind of routers more readable?

Comment: Check req.body.x in each middleware and make a unique route : app.post('/',a,b,c,d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to have two routes for this. You can check for `req.body.X` in middlewares `a` and `b`.

```
// Middlewares a and b
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.body.X){/* Do stuff */} // if is the middleware "a" call next()
                                 // else, is "b" finish with a response i.e. res.send()
  else next();
}

// Middlewares c and d
module.exports = function(){
  // Do whatever, if middleware "c" call next() else finish with a response
}

// Route 
app.post('/', a, b, c, d);
```